# How can I make the output appear in Arabic language when i import stopWords corpus in python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, arabic, corpus, stop-words

i use python 2.7 and  the code as shown here

```
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    sW_list=stopwords.words('arabic')
    print (sW_list)
```

and the output was :

```
    [u'\u0625\u0630', u'\u0625\u0630\u0627', u'\u0625\u0630\u0645\u0627' ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing a list uses the `repr` of the list elements.

```
sW_list = [u'\u0625\u0630', u'\u0625\u0630\u0627', u'\u0625\u0630\u0645\u0627' ]
print(' '.join(sW_list))
```

produces

```
إذ إذا إذم
```